# Android eclipse how to start a new activity on button click

Tags: android, eclipse, button, android-activity

I am trying to make it so that when the user presses a button on the default activity, it opens a new activity.

Here's what I've got.

The code for the button:

```
android:onClick="openmenu"
```

The code for the "openmenu" method:

```
public void openmenu(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this , MainMenuPassed.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Cheers guys!

Comment: Okay, so what is wrong? What have you tried? Read: http://stackoverflow.com/about

Comment: And your problem is...

Comment: did you define the button in the class or does it just reside in the layout?

Comment: Try to add your `MainMenuPassed.class` in manifest.

Comment: Post _all_ the code used for this.

Comment: Post more of your code to get viable help with this.  Post your logcat output if you are getting errors.  Ask a concrete question.

Comment: Tell us what's the problem so we can give you a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can do workaround like :

Define an Id for your button in xml layout

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button Text"
  />
```

Now in your Activity Class

```
 public class MyActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{



   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
    final Button button =(Button) findVieById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);

   }

   @Override
   protected void onClick(View view) {

     switch(v.getId){
       case R.id.button :
          Intent intent = new Intent(this , MainMenuPassed.class);
          startActivity(intent);
       break;

     }
  }

 }
```